# Change default systemd user target

Tags: systemd, systemd-user

I'd like to change the default target launched by `systemd --user`.

From ArchLinux wiki:

> When systemd user instance starts, it brings up the target default.target

From `man 7 systemd.special`:

> When systemd runs as a user instance, the following special units are available, which have similar definitions as their system counterparts: exit.target, default.target, shutdown.target, sockets.target, timers.target, paths.target, bluetooth.target, printer.target, smartcard.target, sound.target.

To change the system-wide default target, you can run `systemctl set-default name`. To change the default user target, you call `systemctl --user set-default name`.

The problem is, on what target should my custom target depend so that no other user-defined targets are broken? Obviously, depending on `default.target` doesn't help :)

Comment: `graphical-session.target` could work if you use a desktop-environment which implements it AND you are expecting a desktop to be available for your units.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat /usr/lib/systemd/user/default.target
# ...
[Unit]
Description=Default
Documentation=man:systemd.special(7)
Requires=basic.target
After=basic.target
AllowIsolate=yes
```

So it seems depending on the `basic.target` should work. I did it and everything seems to work as it should. However, if you have any more insights, please, share them here :)